# Textarea onfocus, onblur and php

Tags: php, forms

Can I put php in onfocus and onblur?. In the code below, is there a way I can I write:

```
comment<?php echo $row['titol_post'] ?>
```

in the place that now there is comment?

```
<?php $result = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM blog WHERE id= 1") or die(mysql_error());
while($row = mysql_fetch_array($result))  { ?>

<Form id="comentari" method="POST" action="rebut.php"> 

    <textarea name="text_comment" rows="2" cols="30"
        onfocus="if (this.value=='Comment') this.value = '';" 
        onblur="if (this.value=='') this.value = 'Comment';">Comment</textarea>    
    <input type="submit"  class="boto" name="comentari" value="enviar"/>

</Form>

<?php } ?>
```

Comment: Don't abuse `value` for `<label>` it is horribly inaccessible.

Comment: @Quentin: what's the best way to do it?

Comment: `<label for="foo">Comment</label><textarea id="foo" name="bar"></textarea>`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes, you can do that.

```
 <textarea name="text_comment" rows="2" cols="30"
    onfocus="if (this.value=='Comment') this.value = '';" 
    onblur="if (this.value=='') this.value = 'Comment';">Comment<?php echo $row['titol_post'] ?></textarea>    
<input type="submit"  class="boto" name="comentari" value="enviar"/>
```

However, you can't do that within the tags for `onblur/onfocus`. That is, mix up Javascript(client-side) and PHP(server-side).

Comment: And can I store the value <?php echo $row['titol_post'] ?> in a var and then put it in onfocus, onblur?

Comment: No, the PHP code is executed before the Javascript code, on server-side. Whereas, JS is executed client-side. Hence, the PHP code cannot be executed on the fly, unless you use AJAX. But, in this case, that's not what you want to do.

Answer (score 0):

Depends, the php gets processed before the html gets sent to the browser, so if it is a fixed value, yes, but if the value depends on things that are selected on the page or for example javascript, then no.

Comment: How could it be if the php gets processed before the html?

Answer (score 0):

PHP runs on the server. It will never be seen by the client, meaning you can have PHP perform output anywhere in a document. PHP couldn't care less if you're writing into a onwhatever tag attribute, or simply outputting plain text, or outputting the raw binary contents of a .jpg file. It simply doesn't matter to PHP.